# Is there anyway to tell that a Guava Cache was constructed with stats disabled?

Tags: java, caching, guava

> **recordStats**
>   `public CacheBuilder<K,V> recordStats()`
>   Enable the accumulation of [`CacheStats`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#stats()) during the operation of the cache. **Without this `Cache.stats()` will return zero for all statistics**. Note that recording stats requires bookkeeping to be performed with each operation, and thus imposes a performance penalty on cache operation.

From JavaDocs for [`CacheBuilder.recordStats()`][2], emphasis added.

From what I can tell, there is no way to distinguish between a cache that has never been called and a cache that was constructed without `recordStats()` being called to enable the accumulation of stats. The [`Cache`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#stats()) interface itself doesn't seem to expose any indication. Am I wrong?

If there is no such method or flag recorded, why not? 9 times out of 10, it should be pretty obvious that your cache is in fact being invoked, but I wasted an hour today trying to figure out why my cache wasn't recording stats...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No, and unfortunately there's not going to be.](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2114)

> [**kevinb9n**](https://github.com/kevinb9n) commented 2015-07-30T18:17:42Z
>   I remember agonizing over whether to try to change the behavior to return -1s years ago, and unfortunately we already felt it was too late. It's also not feasible to add new interface methods at this point. We are sorry.
>
> With interfaces *no* changes are ever backward-compatible; it must always break either a consumer or an implementor. In this case every concrete class implementing Cache outside Guava would break. After we're on Java 8, we can add interface methods by supplying a reasonable "default" implementation. But note that in this case the best we could do is probably `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();` which isn't too exciting.

Comment: Conspicuous timing! Someone asked on Github just 8 days before I asked here. Anyways, thanks very much for the link.